# Can not dismiss GKGameCenterViewController when using SwiftUI UIViewControlllerRepresentable

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, game-center, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

I have a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` implementing a `GKGameCenterViewController` using SwiftUI. I have done all necessary setup with Game Center and this `GKGameCenterViewController` does appear when called in my SwiftUI view. However, I can't dismiss it. I know a `Coordinator` is required to implement the `GKGameCenterControllerDelegate` and I have done so. But it still does not dismiss. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
struct GameCenterView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: GKGameCenterViewController, context: Context) {

    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> GKGameCenterViewController {
        let vc = GKGameCenterViewController()
        vc.delegate = context.coordinator
        return vc
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        var parent: GameCenterView

        func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(_ gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController) {
            gameCenterViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        init(_ parent: GameCenterView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a fix.

`delegate` looks wrong.
You can do with `gameCenterDelegate`.

like this:

```
vc.gameCenterDelegate = context.coordinator
```